# Glade with Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, glade

Is there a way to get Glade, or any similar software, to work with Tkinter? I'm unable to install WxPython or any other libraries, so I need something compatible with what's installed on OSX.6 by default.

Comment: Depending on what's your goal, there are othe GUI options, like Gooey that uses Tkinter. Also, you can build your own templates, wich are pure Python at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get glade or other not-designed-for-tkinter GUI tools to work with tkinter. At least, not without a tremendous amount of effort.